# Run a bash script at instance startup but not at reboot

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For some instance types in AWS, there is instance store 0 available which you can select during launch instance wizard at 'add storage'. I found that this instance store 0 needs to be reformatted and remounted every time instance starts. However, once mounted, the mount remains intact after a reboot but not for instance start. I execute following code via /etc/rc.local which basically serves the purpose.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FSTYPE=xfs
DEVICE=/dev/xvdb

mkfs -t $FSTYPE $DEVICE
umount -f /mnt > /dev/null 2>&1
mount $DEVICE /mnt
chmod 777 /mnt
chmod +t /mnt
exit
```

But rc.local gets executed at reboot as well as during startup. Is there an elaborate way in Centos 7 wherein this script runs only during instance startup and not during reboots?

Comment: This is was `user-data` scripts are for.

Comment: @jordanm AWS has this _Important_ tip - *User data scripts and cloud-init directives only run during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched.* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts